# having a button apply effect xcode

Tags: xcode, uibutton

I want to apply a filter effect to photos I capture in my app. I need 3 buttons to call these effects (i.e. one for Black and White, one for Sepia, and one for Vintage). So here's my question. Below you will see a code when my images are saved. You will see in there "img = [img e1]". This saves the image as black and white. If I did "img = [img e2]" it would be sepia. My code works as it is if I wanted that effect be permanent. The problem is that I need buttons to change between different e numbers if this makes sense. Sorry if this isn't explained that well.

```
- (void)captureEnded:(CameraView *)camView {
NSLog(@"%f, %f", [camView capturedImage].size.width, [camView capturedImage].size.height)

UIImage *img = [camView capturedImage];
img = [img e1];
   img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[ self rotateImage:img angle:90 ].CGImage
                          scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationUp];

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare

```
UIImage *img;
```

in the header .h file and in your main class write three buttons actions

```
-(IBAction) nbutton1{
```

img = [img e1];

}

```
-(IBAction) nbutton2{
```

img = [img e2];

}

```
-(IBAction) nbutton3{
```

img = [img e3];

}

Answer (score 0):

Array of method name

```
NSArray *methodArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"e1", @"e2", @"e3", nil];
```

Declare methods with name used in array

```
- (void)e1
{
    // Code for Black & White effect
}

- (void)e2
{
    // Code for Sepia effect
}

- (void)e3
{
    // Code for Vignet effect
}
```

now to call method with array object use following code

```
[self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString([methodArray objectAtIndex:0])]; // call to method e1
[self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString([methodArray objectAtIndex:1])]; // call to method e2
[self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString([methodArray objectAtIndex:2])]; // call to method e3
```